# Fill an arraylist with another arraylist using foreach

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

Just a simple question.
How Can I fill an arraylist using another arraylist which contains objects and using foreach?

thank you
Regards

Comment: Show your first attempt OR at least your both list datatypes

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just use addAll

Comment: sample input output?

Answer (score 5):

First/better option:

```
targetArrayList.addAll(sourceArrayList);
```

Using forEach (Java 8):

```
sourceArrayList.forEach(element -> targetArrayList.add(element));
```

Using a for loop:

```
for(Object element : sourceArrayList) {
    targetArrayList.add(element);
}
```

Comment: The `forEach` option could just be `sourceList.forEach(targetList::add)`

Comment: @khelwood: True. There are indeed multiple variations for each option :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `ArrayList<myObject> list1` , `ArrayList<myObject> list2`

```
for(myObject obj : list1){
list2.add(obj);
}
```

Better answer use [addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) list2.addAll(list1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) of Collections.

```
ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
list2.addAll(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your object type of data like this

```
 class UserData{
        String user;
        String pass;
    }
```

And you put it into an [ArrayList][1] and fill data into this from your external or any internal source.

```
  ArrayList <UserData> newInfoList = new ArrayList <UserData>()

    for (UserData d:??? ) //??? Means your current arraylist
    {
    newInfoList.add(d);
    }
```